# Why does mobile does not accept avoiding asc when typing in textarea?

Tags: html, textarea

The JavaScript code below, which serves to "avoid" character > (asc 60) only works on desktop devices and not mobile devices.

```html
<textarea name='notes' id='ta' wrap='physical' cols='65' rows='8' style='width: 80%;' tabindex='14'></textarea>
    
    <script>
    var ta = document.getElementById("ta");
    ta.addEventListener('keypress',
        function (e) {
           if (e.keyCode == 60) {
               alert('do not use <');
               e.preventDefault();
           }
        }
    );
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you have an error message on mobile devices. At which line, the code stops executing?

Answer (score 0):

`Keydown` is known to be a hit and miss when it comes to mobile because some browsers do not support it. Having said that, `keydown` should work, but to be on the absolute safe side i'd use `input`, see my snippet below.

```html
<textarea name='notes' id='ta' wrap='physical' cols='65' rows='8' style='width: 80%;' tabindex='14'></textarea>
    
    <script>
    var ta = document.getElementById("ta");
    ta.addEventListener('input',
        function (e) {
           if (e.data == "<") {
               alert('do not use <');
               ta.value = ta.value.replace(/</g, "");
               e.preventDefault();
           }
        }
    );
    </script>
```

Comment: First you should check on a mobile device if this snippet works. If this answer works, accepting the answer will help people viewing this post in the future find what they need. Accept by clicking the green checkmark on the left of the answer. But ONLY do this if you are sure that this answer works on a mobile device.

Comment: @Roseli if you think this is the solution would you mind accepting this answer to help people in the future find their answer?